# is there any way to find the maximal length of cycle in a permutation group?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, gap, permutation-cycles

How we can find the biggest cycle of a permutation group with given the set of generators ? is there any algorithm or theorem for that? 
Or how we can find the set of generators with biggest cycle as much as possible?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function

Comment: The "obvious" approach is to find representatives of the conjugacy classes of $G$ and then just check directly. (Obviously there exists an algorithm to do it! What are you really asking?)

Comment: @DerekHolt could you please explain it more?

Comment: @user9272398 cycle structure is an invariant of a conjugacy class - if you know their representatives, you can find out which are cycles, and what is their maximal length.